# [MongoDB]: Add new value to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'am trying a add new value to array inside object, this way:

```
await database.models.updateMany( { <queue> }, { $push: { object: { array: 'Hello, World!' }}});
```

but, thats delete the array inside the object instead of add new value

Comment: Show your schema please

Comment: it has already been resolved, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,

you should be using

```
await database.models.updateMany( { <queue> }, { $push: { 'object.array': 'Hello, World!' }});
```